# OL3 GeoJSON vs. turf GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, geojson, openlayers, intersection, turf

I am using OL3 and I try to inspect whether two lines are intersecting or not using turf. I used GeoJSON in OL3 and fed the lines into the intersect() in turf but I get Unknown GeoJSON type. 
here is my code:

```
lineStringdraw.on('drawend', function(e2) {
var featureEnd = e2.feature;
checkIntersection(featureEnd);
});

function checkIntersection(currentFeature){
var features = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
var geoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
geoJSON = geoJSON.writeFeature(currentFeature);
for (i=0; (features.length)>i;i++){
var feature = features[i];
geoJSON_i = geoJSON.writeFeature(feature);
var intersectionStatus = turf.intersect(geoJSON,geoJSON_i);
$('#infoList').append(intersectionStatus);
}
}
```

here is piece of the OL3 GeoJSON:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-8236104.129670544,4977029.890789877],[-8236634.411554272,4974407.145256842]]},"properties":null}
```

Does anyone know why it is not working or what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Turf follows the [GeoJSON specification](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html). One aspect of this specification is that geometries should use WGS 84 coordinates. Each coordinate should look like: `[longitude, latitude]`. Your sample data is not valid WGS 84 lon/lat.

A trick I use with sample datasets is to copy and paste them into http://geojson.io . If the feature does not render normally (it does not with your sample data), there is likely a data problem.

Answer (score 1):

`turf.intersect` Takes two polygons and finds their intersection. (not linestrings) If they share a border, returns the border; if they don't intersect, returns undefined.
here is the doc [turf.intersect](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_intersect.html)

Comment: It does check lineString and I have already implement it. the problem was that the GeoJSON produced by OL3 is not compatible with the GeoJSON in turf, which is weird. I worked around this problem by extracting the coordinates by OL3 and creating GeoJSON using turf. Now it is working. I will add my solution soon. but the question remains: why GeoJSONs are not compatible?